# using of canvas in a layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to use `canvas class` in android layout,like `linear layout` and `relative layout`.I am trying to draw a line in relative layout.

```
public class DrawDemoText extends Activity {

    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.relativeMain);
}

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                    Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    Path path = new Path();
                    path.lineTo(20, 0);
                    path.close();
                    path.offset(90, 120);
                    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use the other xml layout in canvas using the addView(your view ) and  u need to inflate the xml layout when u going to add the View in canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own Layout. Create a `MLayout extends RelativeLayout`, and in your `MLayout` override `onDraw` function, and do there what you want